# Check if message was sent in a thread (discord.py / pycord)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

I need my discord bot to check if slash command is being executed in a thread or not. Couldn't find anything related in the discord.py docs https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html and there's no info on that on stackoverflow or anywhere else :(

I basically need something like `is_thread()` function. If it's even possible. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is most likely `ctx.channel.type` which will tell you the type of channel that the command was executed in. A possible solution for your problem would look something like this:

```
async def creativeName(ctx):
  if ctx.channel.type == "public_thread" or "private_thread":
    # Code to execute if it is in a thread goes here
  else:
    # Code, if any, to execute if it is not in a thread
```